# get the sum of column rows after a mysql JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$r1 = mysql_query("
SELECT *, SUM(bps.price) as sum FROM accounts 
FULL JOIN bps on bps.id = mid
");
echo "Total price: ".$row['price']."<br>" ;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r1))
      {
      echo $row['name']." <b>:::</b>  ".$row['mid']." <b>:::</b>  ".$row['price'];
      echo "<br />";
      }
```

this is my query. I need to get the total(the sum) of the column : bps.price
some of the rows have : 10.5 , others -5.5 etc... in other words some are negative values and others are positive.It will list all the results then at the end display the sum of column price.

Comment: You realize you're trying to echo out a row before you've even run the query?

Comment: oh sorry yeah .I moved it to the bottom thanks Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work the way you want? I'm not sure which columns belong to which tables, just edit the table names (a / b) as needed...

```
$r1 = mysql_query("
SELECT *, sum(a.price) as sum FROM accounts as a 
FULL JOIN bps as b on a.mid = b.id
");
echo "Total price: ".$row['sum']."<br>" ;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r1))
      {
      echo $row['a.name']." <b>:::</b>  ".$row['a.mid']." <b>:::</b>  ".$row['a.price'];
      echo "<br />";
      }
```

Comment: this didnt work  it returns 1 row as far as price goes.I am thinking about storring all the sum values in an array and do array_sum with php ... I think this should do it

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(bps.price) FROM accounts a
FULL JOIN bps on bps.id = a.mid
```

That would work, right?  It will sum positive and negative values, that doesn't matter.